# Hot to read Compressed NFT (bubblegum) on-chain

Tags: solana-program, rust, metaplex, bubblegum

I need to read Compressed NFT (bubblegum) to check NFT owner on-chain.

Do I need to get leaf owner from merkle tree?
Can you show me how to do in rust program?